# Docker compose: angular container can't send request to backend container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When i worked without docker, i sended requests to this basic path

```
http://localhost:8080/api/v3
```

Now i am trying send to:

```
http://backend:8080/api/v3
```

But i get

**GET http://backend:8080/api/v3/developers  net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

How look my ui container:

```
  front:
    image: myimage
    container_name: front
    build:
      context: path
    environment:
      API_HOST: backend
      API_PORT: 8080
    ports:
      -  4200:4200
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

**P.S. backend works perfectly**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending a request from your front wich is hosted by your navigator into your local host environment (127.0.0.1). So you can not send a request to your backend because your are outside of the docker-compose internal network. Replace `API_HOST=127.0.0.1` and make sure sur your backend container expose the 8080 port.

Comment: I am sure that backend runs on 8080, because i can open it.
I changed my API_HOST to 127.0.0.1, but it doesn't work

Comment: By the way, they runs on different containers. When i connected database to backed, i just wrote ```jdbc:mysql://containerName:PORT/database``` and itt worked

Comment: As the error say, you can not access to 'backend' host. Maybe you have an new error now with CORS Policies error. But this is out of the scope.

Comment: Yes, the connection to your database work because you are inside the docker-compose context. This is because your database and your backend are on the same network

Comment: Angular is also with them on docker-compose. And how should look url in which i will send request?

Comment: Try to set 'localhost' instead of 127.0.0.1... The URL sensed from your frontend hosted by your local navigator should look `http://localhost:8080/api/v3`

Comment: The server wich host your frontend is inside your docker-compose that's right. But the files served by your server are read into your local navigator. So the script is executed from your localhost navigator, wich he don't now who is 'backend'

Comment: Well, it works when am trying to send request to localhost.
But i am not certain that it is right choise )